# In clojure enlive how to create template to add values and keys from a map

Tags: clojure, enlive

I want to create a template with Clojure's Enlive for a "table" like html page, that should have a header and rows. I want to populate this "table" with data that comes from this map. Basicaly I want to populate header with keys, and cells with vals from each of the maps that come from :event-data key.

```
(def dummy-content
{:title "Events Mashup"
 :event-data [{ :event-name "event name 1"
                    :performer "performer 1"
                  :date "date 1"
                       :start-time "start time 1"
                       :end-time "end time 1"}
  {:event-name "event name 2"
                       :performer "performer 2"
                      :date "date 2"
                       :start-time "start time 2"
                       :end-time "end time 2"}]})
```

My snippets and template look like this:

```
(defsnippet header-cell "index.html" [:.psdg-top-cell] [value] [:.psdg-top-cell]

(defsnippet value-cell "index.html" [:.psdg-right] [value] [:.psdg-right] 

(deftemplate mshp "index.html" [content] 
 [:.psdg-top] (append (for [c (keys content)] (header-cell c)))
 [:.psdg-right] (append (for [v (vals content)] (value-cell v))))
```

And index.html has these tags, that are rellevant for this template.

```
<div id="psdg-top">
<div class="psdg-top-cell" style="width:129px; text-align:left; padding- left:24px;">Summary</div>
<div class="psdg-top-cell">Website.com</div>
</div>
<div class="psdg-right">10 000</div>
```

When I  call the template I get this error:

```
 => (mshp (:event-data dummy-content))
```

ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry  clojure.lang.APersistentMap$ValSeq.first (APersistentMap.java:183)
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring when you call `(keys content)`, because `(:event-data dummy-content)` returns a vector, and `keys` won't work on a vector. You've got two options - you can either define your header columns elsewhere, or just take them from the first element in the vector, like this: `(keys (first content))`.

**Edit**

I've had a go at replicating what you set out in the question, but fixing the errors, and you can find my efforts here: https://www.refheap.com/17659.

If you want something that has a more typical table structure, with the value cells contained in rows, you can try the following. It uses `clone-for` rather than a combination of `append` and `for`, and uses `nth-of-type` to just return the first "psdg-top-cell" (otherwise there would be twice as many)

```
(def template
  (html-snippet
   "<div id=\"psdg-top\">
    <div class=\"psdg-top-cell\">Summary</div>
    <div class=\"psdg-top-cell\">Website.com</div>
    </div>
    <div class=\"psdg-right\">10 000</div>"))

(defsnippet header-row template [[:.psdg-top-cell (nth-of-type 1)] ] [headers]
  (clone-for [h headers] 
     (content h)))

(defsnippet value-row template [:.psdg-right] [values]
  (clone-for [v values]
     (content v)))

(deftemplate mshp template [events]
  [:#psdg-top] (content (header-row (map name (keys (first events)))))
  [:.psdg-right] (clone-for [e events]
                        (do->
                         (wrap :div {:class "psdg-row"})
                         (content (value-row (vals e))))))
```

Comment: it works for now, when I call it like this (print (apply str (mshp (:event-data dummy-content)))), it seems ok, except that first gives me only first map...

Comment: I don't know why this works => (html/sniptest "<div class=\"psdg-top-cell\">Website.com</div>" [:.psdg-top-cell] (html/content 
                                 (name (first(keys (first (:event-data dummy-content)))))))
"<div class=\"psdg-top-cell\">end-time</div>" and defsnippet doesn't change anything?

Comment: @Vesna I edited my answer to provide a complete code sample which I think will help

Comment: thanks, I'll accept your answer, this will do, and now to resolve the next issue :)